# Where did the review tasks go?

Tags: support, review

I wasn't on this site for like 2 months or so and now I can't find the review tasks. Did they move or got removed?

Comment: The minimum reputation requirement for certain review queues was increased. You'll need to reach 500 points before the queues are visible again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only users with more than 500 reputation can review posts. As you were not active for long time, you didn't know that this privilege got changed.

Visit the [Stack Overflow privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page for more details.